# Is there a defined difference between the word "policy" and the phrase "policy measure"

Tags: nouns, synonyms, academia, politics

I've seen a lot of things crop up talking about "policy measures" recently.  I've even caught myself about to use (or misuse) it .  But does it mean anything unique, or is it just a redundant way of saying "policies"?

Comment: I suppose a policy measure is some document or action that implements or defines a policy.  But I also suppose that many people use "policy measure" when they ought to be using "policy."

Comment: could you clarify that first point a bit?

Comment: The UK government currently has an economic *policy* of eliminating its budget deficit by 2020. One *policy measure* they are implementing in pursuit of this goal is the limitation of welfare benefits payable to any one household to £23,000 pa in London, and £20,000 per annum throughout the rest of the country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Policy" is the principles you apply to a situation. A "policy measure" is something you do to implement that policy.

For example:

> It is the policy of StackExchange to make it easy to ask questions.
>
> A policy measure is to make the reputation threshold for asking questions zero.